# Detectando pressionamento das teclas de volume no Android

Tags: java, android

Encontrei uma solução paliativa, que fica monitorando a alteração do volume do sistema em si. Quando o volume diminui, por exemplo, de 10 para 9, o programa redefine o volume de volta para 10 (fingindo que não houve mudança no volume) e realiza a ação desejada (idem para quando o volume aumenta).

Essa solução funciona em vários dispositivos, mas acho essa solução meio "gambiarra".

Alguém conhece um modo, que não envolva root ou custom ROMS, para monitorar e tratar o pressionamento das teclas físicas de volume com a tela bloqueada, a partir de um serviço?

Valeu pessoal!

**Atualização**

Tipos de solução como a que o GravityBox usa só funcionam se o aparelho estiver com root... Ainda assim, gostaria de algo o mais parecido possível:

[ModVolumeKeySkipTrack.java no GitHub](https://github.com/C3C0/GravityBox/blob/master/src/com/ceco/gm2/gravitybox/ModVolumeKeySkipTrack.java)

Answer (score 1):

Monitorar com uma espécie de serviço? Não vejo outra forma além de utilizar o AlarmManager para a cada x segundos verificar se houve alteração no volume.

Porém, se for na Activity, você pode utilizar essa solução:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN||) {
        // Sua ação aqui
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Comment: Pois é, vou reeditar a pergunta. Teria que ser de dentro de um serviço.

Comment: Valeu! Mas a solução com o AlarmManager não conseguiria agir tão rapidamente quanto aquela solução que já encontrei. Tem que ser algo instantâneo, ou o mais próximo possível disso.

Comment: Mas você pode definir o AlarmManager pra a cada 1 segundo.

Comment: Esse tipo de solução que fica sempre executando e verificando (conhecido como pooling) acaba gastando mais CPU e bateria do que o necessário, além de o tempo de resposta nem sempre ser satisfatório. Nesse caso, com a solução que eu encontrei de monitorar o volume via callback, não há pooling, e o tempo de resposta é quase instantâneo... Mas ainda assim, o usuário sente por um breve momento (poucos milissegundos) que houve uma mudança no volume :( Eu queria evitar isso, e tentar ser notificado sobre o pressionamento físico da tecla, se possível.

Comment: Creio que a solução dentro dos critérios que você determinou não exista, pelo menos não para acessarmos sem Root.

Comment: Eu também estou chegando a essa conclusão. Já revirei a internet, sem sucesso. Mas sempre há esperanças ;)