# Capturar eventos no botão de volume

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Estou tentando registrar e capturar os eventos nos botões de volume do Android, para poder iniciar e parar um serviço.

Pesquisando encontrei varias soluções, utilizando BroadcastReceiver, mas parece que nenhuma está funcionando para o meu caso.

O que fiz até agora foi basicamente isso (que não está a funcionar):

Criei um BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MediaButtonReceiver", "onReceive");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            switch (event.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Volume down!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Volume up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Registrei o *receiver* no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

E registrei no `onCreate` de minha `Activity` *main*:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    ComponentName rec = new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(rec);
}
```

Mas parece que está faltando algo, ou algo está incorreto, pois o método `onReceive` do `MediaButtonReceiver`, não está sendo chamada ao pressionar os botões de volume do dispositivo.

**Estou executando no Android 5.0.**

> Já vi [essa pergunta similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13862/2998) que está sem solução.
>
> - Aceito soluções que exijam acesso root (dispositivos rooteados).

Comment: Fernando, teria que ser a partir de uma `Activity` de seu app ou precisa saber mesmo sem seu app estar em uso?

Comment: @Wakim, teria que ser fora do App, é tipo para iniciar um serviço, apartir de qualquer lugar, mas o app tem que estar em background.

Answer (score 3):

Em vez de `action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"` use `action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"` no *intent-filter* do seu *receiver*:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

<sub>Agradeça ao autor desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443880/2556111) no SOen.</sub>

Terá de alterar o *receiver* para tratar os *Extras* passados:

```
public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int prevVolume;
        int volume;
        if ("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            volume = (int)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
            prevVolume = (int)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_PREV_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
            if(volume < prevVolume) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Volume down!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(volume > prevVolume){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Volume up!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

O problema que vai encontrar com esta implementação é que, quando o volume chegar ao valor mínimo ou máximo, o `volume` e `prevVolume` serão sempre iguais, não permitindo saber qual dos botões foi premido.

Uma coisa que verifiquei, que para a qual não encontrei explicação, foi que o *receiver* é chamado duas vezes por cada vez que se carrega num botão.
Na primeira vez os valores são diferentes, na segunda são iguais.
Da forma como está o código a segunda chamada é ignorada.

Comment: Ontem no fim do dia, tinha achado algo do tipo que você falou, utilizando `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION`, ao testar constatei o mesmo que você citou, que por algum motivo o método era chamado 2 vezes e não era explicito qual dos botões teria sido pressionado. Fiz uma implementação do `onReceive` na mesma ideia da sua, ignorando a segunda chamada, mas pelo fato do volume ao chegar aos extremos não ser possível identificar o botão, estou ignorando o botão pressionado e tratando apenas como um evento único. Vou aguardar alguma outra possível solução, caso não haja, vou utilizar está.

Comment: Chegou a encontrar alguma outra solução?

Comment: Não, acabei abandonando está implementação!